# How to Open window form with specified pair and arrange on desktop

Tags: c#, .net, window

Hi I need to open multiple window form(form is same) on button click . I am able to open it using following code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int iPair = int.Parse( textBox1.Text);
        int iDeskTopWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
        int iDeskTopHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;

        int iPreviousFormX = 0;
        int iPreviousFormY = 0;

        int iRowWidth = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i< iPair; i++)
        {
            var form = new Form1();
            Size FormSize = form.Size;
            int iWidth = FormSize.Width;
            int iHeight = FormSize.Height;
            int iNewXLocation = iWidth * i;
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            int iTotalDesktopWidthNeeded = iPair * iWidth;

            if (iNewXLocation + iWidth < iDeskTopWidth)
            {
                form.DesktopLocation = new Point(iNewXLocation, 0);
            }
            else if(iRowWidth + iWidth < iDeskTopWidth)
            {
                form.DesktopLocation = new Point(iPreviousFormX, iDeskTopHeight -(iDeskTopHeight- iHeight));
                iPreviousFormX = iPreviousFormX + iWidth;
                iPreviousFormY = iPreviousFormY + iHeight;
                iRowWidth = iRowWidth + iWidth;
            }
            else
            {
                form.DesktopLocation = new Point(iPreviousFormX, iDeskTopHeight - (iDeskTopHeight - iHeight));
                iPreviousFormX = iPreviousFormX + iWidth;
                iPreviousFormY = iPreviousFormY + iHeight;
            }
            form.Show();
            Point p = new Point(iNewXLocation, 0);
        }
    }
```

**What i am trying to achieve :**

1: each time if user enter number of pair (ex :10 ) and click enter 10 pair of that form should open. if width of desktop end then it should open below that.

**Problem i am facing :**

1: It goes beyond desktop with if i open large pair like 14.
2: if i open 4 pair in one click, and then second time i want to open 4 more pair on another click. it opens on existing location. but it should open on new location like below that.

any suggestion would be appreciated. here are image how i want to open form.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1LKK.png)

Comment: A global variable to indicate how many forms have been opened so you can use that to calculate the starting place for the next click. Though you may need to consider what should happen if any existing form is closed or moved.

Comment: i did that in code. but having problem if desktop width end. it opens new pair beyond desktop width.

Comment: You need to look at your code very carefully. Maintaining a current X & Y location would be a good idea - X is incremented by the width after each new form - if it is beyond the width of the screen then it is reset to 0 & the Y position is incremented by the height.